# Enlight_Controller_Action_PreDispatch_Frontend is not working in Plugin.php class

Tags: php, event-handling, symfony4, shopware

I am creating a shopware 5 plugin. I want to display something after the categories on every page.
I am using this code to do my task as suggested in this [video](https://academy.shopware.com/courses/take/developer-training-basic-english/lessons/4536444-4-2-subscriber-method-global-events), but the event is not getting recognized.

Here is my code

```
<?php
namespace MyPlugin;

use Shopware\Components\Plugin;

class MyPlugin extends Plugin{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'Enlight_Controller_Action_PreDispatch_Frontend' => 'onPreDispatch'
        ];
    }

    public function onPreDispatch(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
    {
        $controller = $args->getSubject();
        $view = $controller->View();

        $view->addTemplateDir(__DIR__.'/Resources/views');
    }
}
```

**frontend/index/index.tpl**

```
{extends file="parent:frontend/index/index.tpl"}
{block name="frontend_index_navigation_categories_top" append}
    <div>my items here</div>
{/block}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As I remember the `append`-Keywoard shouldn't be used in Shopware anymore. Use `{$smarty.block.parent}` instead.
Also you should create an EventSubscriber explained [here](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/plugin-quick-start/#subscriber-classes).

If this still doesn't work please check your cache and that the plugin is activated